# Allow requests to Kubernetes API from an init container with Istio CNI plugin

Tags: kubernetes, istio, cni

I had istio configured but without the CNI addon enabled.

In that time, I had an init container with a service account that would call the Kubernetes API to verify a couple of things (via kubectl).

Since I enabled the CNI addon, this init container fails with the following message:

> The connection to the server 10.23.64.1:443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

I tried removing all my network policies to see if that was the issue, but same result.
I also gave the service account that this pods uses the cluster-admin role, but it didn't do the trick.

I tested with both 1.6 and 1.7 branches of Istio.

What is the issue here? Other pods without this init container work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have init container network connectivity with istio cni enabled please follow the guide for a workaround from istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/cni/#compatibility-with-application-init-containers):

> #### Compatibility with application init containers
>
> The Istio CNI plugin may cause networking connectivity problems for any application  `initContainers`. When using Istio CNI,  `kubelet`  starts an injected pod with the following steps:
>
> 1. The Istio CNI plugin sets up traffic redirection to the Istio sidecar proxy within the pod.
> 2. All init containers execute and complete successfully.
> 3. The Istio sidecar proxy starts in the pod along with the pod’s other containers.
>
> Init containers execute before the sidecar proxy starts, which can result in traffic loss during their execution. Avoid this traffic loss with one or both of the following settings:
>
> - Set the  `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges`  annotation to disable redirecting traffic to any CIDRs the init containers communicate with.
> - Set the  `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts`  annotation to disable redirecting traffic to the specific outbound ports the init containers use.